# PIL set pixel as transparent/blank

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a rule set, if a color is in a list for this cell delete the cell like so

```
image = PILImage.open('revamp'+img_url)
img = image
random_name = random_filename(path="revamp/media/colorfest/")
img.save(random_name, "PNG")

pixels = image.load()   
for pos in area_id:
    pixel = pixels[pos[0], pos[1]]
    pixel = [pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2]]

    if pixel in colors:
        img.putpixel([pos[0], pos[1]], (0, 0, 0, 0))

img.save(random_name, "PNG")
response['status'] = 'ok'
```

here's what I get, blacked out cells

[image]

original image [image]

Comment: And what is your problem now?

Comment: I guess you have what you wanted. What else do you need?